# Which word for "sun" should I use?

Tags: word-choice

It's a weird question, but I gotta ask.
Let's say I keep sneezing a lot and want to explain to someone that it's because of the sun. So in English I'd simply say "It's the sun." as an explanation.
So how do I say something like this in Japanese? Which word for "sun" do I use? 日、太陽、天日?
Is saying 「日ですから。」correct?

Answer (score 2):

"The sun" itself is 太陽, so you could say:

> 太陽のせいです。 (It's because of/due to the sun)

EDIT: Although not incorrect grammatically speling, the following sentence does not sound natural (please see the comment by @Naruto):

> 太陽でくしゃみします 。( [I/You] sneeze due to the sun, sounds like "[I/You] sneeze using the sun").

However, I don't see the connection between sneezing and the sun. If you can provide more context beyond "It's the sun", we will be able to assist you further.

Also note that both せいで and で are used only when the outcome is something negative (like becoming ill, having a sneeze or such). You can't use them for positive outcomes.

Comment: some people have a reflex that when they move from a dark space into a well lit space they sneeze. people notice this often when leaving a movie theater outinto a bright daylight.

Comment: Thank you! And the connection between sneezing and the sun is exactly what @A.Ellett mentioned above :) It's can be known as "photic sneeze reflex".

Comment: で has many meanings, and 太陽でくしゃみします sounds to me like "I sneeze using the sun". You have to say 太陽のせいで explicitly. Please don't ask me why...

Comment: @naruto Thanks for pointing out this. Answer edited.

Comment: @A.Ellet and maja, thank you very much for providing context! I've learnt something new. Thanks.

Comment: @maja Also, I've been reading about the photic sneeze reflect, and I think that you might want to say "It's due to the _sunlight_" or "It's due to the _light_", so you could use 日光{にっこう} (sunlight) or 光 {ひかり} (light), instead of 太陽{たいよう} (sun).